# How to start a stopped process in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a stopped process in Linux at a given terminal. Now I am at another terminal. How do I start that process. What kill signal would I send. I own that process.

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can issue a kill -CONT pid, which will do what you want as long as the other terminal session is still around. If the other session is dead it might not have anywhere to put the output.

Comment: +1 For giving correct answer in place my overly hasty, incorrect one!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Dave's answer, there is an [advanced method](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/) to redirect input and output file descriptors of a running program using GDB.

A FreeBSD example for an arbitrary shell script with PID 4711:

```
> gdb /bin/sh 4711
...
Attaching to program: /bin/sh, process 4711
...
(gdb) p close(1)
$1 = 0
(gdb) p creat("/tmp/testout.txt",0644)
$2 = 1
(gdb) p close(2)
$3 = 0
(gdb) p dup2(1,2)
$4 = 2
```

**EDIT** - explanation: this closes filehandle 1, then opens a file, which reuses 1. Then it closes filehandle 2 and duplicates filehandle 1 to 2.

Now this process' `stdout` and `stderr` go to indicated file and are readable from there. If `stdin` is required, you need to `p close(0)` and then attach some input file or PIPE or smth.

For the time being, I could not find a method to remotely `disown` this process from the controlling terminal, which means that when the terminal exits, this process receives  `SIGHUP` signal.

**Note:** If you do have/gain access to the other terminal, you can `disown -a` so that this process will continue to run after the terminal closes.

Comment: That's a cool bit of technology. I hadn't thought of using the debugger to reroute STDOUT.